# How to save all modified files onto GitHub as a temporary backup when they are not ready to be committed?

Tags: git, github

Let's say since yesterday's commit of all files and push to GitHub, several hours have been spent on development, and before leaving work, is there a way to save all modified files onto GitHub so that the files won't be lost even when the hard drive on the notebook goes bad?

I thought I could

```
git checkout -b tmp-work
git commit -am "tmp work"
git push --set-upstream origin tmp-work
```

and in fact, all files are saved onto GitHub, but when I switch back to my original branch, the files were also all committed.

What is a way to save all files onto GitHub but have the original branch untouched? (all those files remain uncommitted).

**Update:** actually, the original branch became having nothing modified...  -- the files were as if I never modified the files since the last commit.  So the goal is really to have the files still modified in that original branch -- just as if I didn't do anything to back up those files.

Comment: "but when I switch back to my original branch, the files were also all committed." This can only happen if you commited the files to the original branch as well.

Comment: I don't think the commands you showed us is what actually happened.  Is this branch shared or are you the only one working on this branch?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I put in the Update of the question, that the files actually became unmodified, going back to the version of some else's commit

Comment: "So the goal is really to have the files still modified in that original branch -- just as if I didn't do anything to back up those files." I do not understand what you mean. Can you provide a simple example which illustrates what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think a generally safe strategy here would be to make a temporary commit locally, then branch off from that temporary commit and push to the remote:

```
# from your current branch
git commit -m 'WIP'
git checkout -b tmp-work
git push origin tmp-work
```

Now all your work is safely on another computer somewhere.  When you return the next day, you can finish the commit and then *amend* that temporary commit via:

```
git commit --amend
```

This will create a new commit in place of the temporary one, rewriting history in the process.  But since you never shared that commit publicly, there are no problems with doing this.

Comment: I believe the OP doesn't want any commits on the main branch. This requires creating the new branch **before** making any commits. The tip for amending a commit is very helpful.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No, I disagree.  The OP most certainly _does_ want this work on the main branch, this is why he is doing that work on the main branch in the first place.  But he wants to also backup that work.  Well, we can't risk pushing to the main branch, but we can create a second backup branch.

Comment: That is what merging is for after the WIP is finished. IMO committing directly to `master` is a poor practice. In my projects, `master` is reserved for stable released code.

Comment: I would rather avoid an unnecesary merge or rebase if possible.  The main focus of this question is how to backup work without pushing the current branch.

Comment: if I have to "rewrite history", it might be scary. Although I don't share that commit publicly, I will push to my forked repo on github, and who knows who might accidentally get my branch there. So I may favor a `git stash` and then `git stash apply` the changes back to my old branch

Comment: @太極者無極而生 No...I am saying _not_ to push the local branch with the temporary commit.  Instead, just leave that branch alone on your work computer until you return tomorrow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but the main purpose it to have something backed up online just in case the hard drive fails

Comment: @太極者無極而生 This is precisely why I _also_ suggested branching off from that temporary commit and pushing to your repository.  I get the feeling you did not read/understand my answer at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but, do you have to create the branch and then push to GitHub? And then later on, amend the commit history? So it could create a chaos if somebody accidentally used your backup branch and then the amended branch

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Yes, you would push the backup branch to GitHub.  If someone else uses it, it is his own problem, not yours.  Just give it a name which no one would mistake for something to be used in production.

Comment: I don't like to create problems to the world and then "it is their problems"... but it is just me

Answer (score 0):

> What is a way to save all files onto GitHub but have the original branch untouched?

By creating a new branch and committing to it. Files are only committed to any branch, including the original `master` branch, **when you do it explicitly**. The commands in your question are the exact correct sequence assuming you make your changes after checking out the new branch.

> several hours have been spent on development

I suggest that you make commits more often than this. I try to make commits at least every 15-30 minutes. More often even.

It sounds like you need to develop a work flow that works well for you. In most work flows you will create a new branch for a feature or bug fix. You commit frequently to the new branch in small chunks. Once the feature or bug fix is finished, you then merge the branch into the master branch.

For some tips on creating a work flow, see [Git branching and tagging best practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices). This is a question which I asked when learning git. The answers have some great information as well as links to additional resources.

Comment: Please refrain from dropping extraneous comments under my answer.

Comment: @CodeApprentice you said "I suggest that you make commits more often than this. I try to make commits at least every 15-30 minutes." but actually, there are development rules in some project that you should not commit or push when your change is not ready (not yet done, or could cause tests to fail or break Continuous Integration).

Comment: @太極者無極而生 With git, there is a huge difference between committing and pushing. Also branching and merging is incredibly easy, so branches are often used to track a series of changes which are not yet complete. Once complete the branch can be merged into `master`. Please read the link in my answer for more details.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I do know that some company requires that "each commit to be independently working all well".  For example, if something went wrong, they might use binary search to search for the point when it breaks... imagine if there are some commits that doesn't work...

Comment: @太極者無極而生 "each commit to be independently working all well" can mean that the code compiles and all tests pass. It does not have to mean that a particular feature is complete. Committing only code that compiles is definitely a good practice.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice as I said, I am "in the middle of development and want to make a backup". It maybe even I typed in two more lines and the code doesn't even compile and I have to catch the train or bus and make a backup. So how is it that "all code compiles and all tests pass"?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 You should create a new branch and make commits there. You can then push the new branch to GitHub for backup purposes. You can use `git commit --amend` and `git rebase` to clean up the history before merging with the `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this method should work well:

```
# Let's say your current branch is  some-dev-work
# If you don't know, you can use `git branch` to tell

git stash -u     # for untracked files as well
git checkout -b some-dev-work-tmp-backup
git stash apply
git add .        # assuming you are at the top of the project folder
git commit -am "backup"
git push origin some-dev-work-tmp-backup
git checkout some-dev-work
git stash pop
```

The idea is to use stash to create a temporary copy of changes, which can be applied to your new branch, as well as your current branch.  The `pop` at the end is to clean up the stash stack.

If in the future there can be some `git backup push` command to create a branch and backup to GitHub or wherever your repo is, that's be nice.

Comment: My answer achieves exactly the same thing in about one third of the steps.  By the way, when you do `git stash`, Git makes 2 (sometimes 3) commits under the hood.  In this case, I think making a formal temporary commit would be far less work, and less confusing.

Comment: but like in the comments under your answer... do you need to push your commit to GitHub and then amend / rewrite your history?  Sometimes I don't like `git` because it is too low level. It is like putting on a screw here and put on some glue there when you are more concerned with higher level product design

Comment: by the way, which way actually better? I am not too sure as I am not expert in git. Number of steps can be abstracted away by creating a function or shell script.